# Why was this question whether there a limit on how full of items a car is to be allowed to drive from Mexico to the US closed as opinion-based?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question [Is there a limit on how full of items a car is to be allowed to drive from Mexico to the United States via Sentri lanes, and if so, what's the limit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169297/1810)
was closed as opinion-based. From the [help center](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions):

> - **Opinion-based** - discussions focused on diverse opinions are great, but they just don't fit our format well.
>
> > Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than on facts, references, or specific expertise.
>
> It’s often possible to rewrite opinion-based questions to focus on a more fact-based line of questioning. If you see a way to do this, consider editing the question.

The question [Is there a limit on how full of items a car is to be allowed to drive from Mexico to the United States via Sentri lanes, and if so, what's the limit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169297/1810) is purely fact-based, as it is asking whether there a limit and the answer is either 1) yes 2) no 3) it depends on the opinion of the US CBP officer.

The fact that the answer may be "it depends on the opinion of the US CBP officer." doesn't make it opinion-based: this is a factual answer in itself. https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ delves more into what opinion-based mean, and the opinions they mention are from the answerers (i.e., the question is subjective).

Another way to view it is that if the fact that the answer may be "it depends on the opinion of the immigration/customs/etc. officer", then we would have to close many immigration/customs questions. E.g. the following questions should be closed:

- [What am I supposed to declare when driving from Mexico to the United States, as a US lawful permanent resident?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169275/1810)
- [Why does custom officer stop me for carrying too many credit cards?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169087/1810)
- [Why was this border agent rude to me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168993/1810)
- [Do I need to declare my money (over $10K) in the US if I'm in transit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169075/1810)
- [Can money orders written to myself be used as proof of funds at border control?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/168534/1810)

since the answer may be "it depends on the opinion of the immigration/customs/etc. officer".

So why was the question [Is there a limit on how full of items a car is to be allowed to drive from Mexico to the United States via Sentri lanes, and if so, what's the limit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169297/1810)
closed as opinion-based?

Comment: Not a real reason but you again have a series of questions which are very specific and off the charts for most people.  That makes some people looking harder for close reasons. (One of the close voters mentioned in a comment that they see it as a 'opinion of the border officer' which for them is the reason to close vote.)

Comment: @Willeke Only 3 questions over 3 days on that topic of land-crossing between US and MX, that's not much, esp. given that this is one of the busiest crossings worlwide.

Comment: Franck - as discussed before, we may wish to close some of those other examples you have raised, we may not. In any case, your questions are not like those questions. Continually finding open questions that have a similar high level topic to yours is not an argument for keeping yours open. As we have told you multiple times before, writing/editing your questions to better fit site scope is a much better approach than failing to improve your posts and instead trying to "lawyer up" with discussions like this.

Comment: FYI your example question of declaring money during transit is NOT opinion based.  It is the law.

Comment: @PeterM but the answer may have been "it depends on the opinion of the US CBP officer." if there wasn't a law on it. You can't assume that the OP knows the answer to the question they're asking about.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'm not "lawyer up with discussions like this", just trying to understand the scope of  this website, so that I can "write/edit my questions to better fit site scope". Anyway, instead of banning on the grounds that I'm asking poor questions, how do you suggest that I write/edit my question [Is there a limit on how full of items a car is to be allowed to drive from Mexico to the United States via Sentri lanes, and if so, what's the limit?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/169297/1810) to better fit site scope?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Arguing that the question should have been closed because there *may* have been an answer the mentioned a CBP opinion on a topic that is well and truly known to involve laws, has the appearance that you are arguing in bad faith.

Comment: @PeterM "well and truly known to involve laws" -> not to the OP (and to many of the other people living in one of the >200 countries outside the US), otherwise they wouldn't have asked the question. Assuming that anyone is familiar with the US laws has the appearance that you are arguing in bad faith.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The question was eventually re-opened.

The following explanation of the previous closure was posted as a comment got 9 upvotes, so it seems a few other people agreed:

> Franck - as discussed before, we may wish to close some of those other examples you have raised, we may not. In any case, your questions are not like those questions. Continually finding open questions that have a similar high level topic to yours is not an argument for keeping yours open. As we have told you multiple times before, writing/editing your questions to better fit site scope is a much better approach than failing to improve your posts and instead trying to "lawyer up" with discussions like this. [Rory Alsop](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1381/rory-alsop) [Oct 20 at 13:27](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7157/why-was-this-question-whether-there-a-limit-on-how-full-of-items-a-car-is-to-be#comment16149_7157)